# how to convert current_timestamp() value in to a string in scala

Tags: string, scala, timestamp

I have been trying to add a timestamp to my data frames and persist them in to hive.

But here is the problem: as I cannot use timestamps as a data type in hive version 0.13 I want to convert `current_timestamp()` of the timestamp data type to string so that I can load it in to my hive table.

Here is my timestamp column:

```
[2017-01-12 12:55:55.278] [2017-01-12 12:55:55.278] [2017-01-12 12:55:55.278] [2017-01-12 12:55:55.278] [2017-01-12 12:55:55.278]
```

I have tried this but with no luck:

```
 val ts = current_timestamp()
    val df:SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val date:String = df.format(ts.toLong)
```

Any way to convert the timestamp to string in Scala??

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy than i expected,
I have been appending a timestamp to my data frame like this,

```
val NewDF = oldDF.withColumn("newColumn_name",current_timestamp())
```

And casted the timestamp in to string like this,

```
val NewDF = oldDF.withColumn("newColumn_name",current_timestamp().cast("String"))
```

Hoe this helps some one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
format.format(new java.util.Date())
```

Comment: import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val ts =format.format(new java.util.Date())

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val AppendDF = myDF.withColumn("timestamp_val",ts)
 while compiling
 found   : String
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
[error] val AppendDF = myDF.withColumn("timestamp_val",ts)
[error]

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date.   with format.format(current_timestamp())

Comment: While this piece of code may answer the question, it is better to include a description of what the problem was, and how your code will tackle the given problem. For the future, here is some information, [how to crack a awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on Stack Overflow.